Как в телеграм bot API в методе getUpdates получить последнее 10 сообщений
Есть у меня бот в телеграмме. Люди ему отсылают сообщение я хочу получить последние 10 сообщений которые отправлены боту. Но сообщений больше 100 и я не знаю id последнего чтобы сделать так https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$tgBotToken.'/getUpdates?offset=X
Как можно получить последнее 10 сообщений?

Если вам нужны только эти 10 а остальные можно выкинуть, то запросите offset=-10, это документированное поведение

Просто получите список всех непрочитанных сообщений, этого можно добиться убрав атрибут offset, результатом будет JSON объект, пройдитесь с конца этого объект отсчитав 10 элементов и получите 10 последних непрочитанных сообщений
